# How to show "Back" option in IOS devices for InappBrowsers in Ionic 5?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am using [InAppBrowser Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) in my Ionic 5 project . My expectation is to have a back button visible in InappBrowser in order to return to original app (which is usually present in Ios) , but as per my current implementation the Back option is not visible in ios device.
below is the code I am using -

> this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_blank', { location: 'no', hardwareback: 'yes', fullscreen: 'no' });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS there is no "back" button but "Done" button (which is the same, takes you back to the app). It should already display, you can't disable it, so you should see a blue "Done" button.

If location is false, the Done button does not appear. Then you need to set the option "footer" to true, to display the Done button at the bottom.

With the options closebuttoncolor and closebuttoncaption you can change the text and the color, so change the text to "Back".

Comment: with my current implementation, I dont see anything on the upperside of my screen, actually the inappbrowser is taking over the entire screen.

Comment: You need to set the option footer to true. I update my answer